# rails route: same url with different id parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

- ruby 2.0.0p247
- Rails 4.0.0

Is it possible the same url contain different id parameters?

Let me explain with more detail. I desire these relative paths:

- recipes/vegetarian (recipes/:kind_id)
- recipes/drinks (receitas/:category_id)

"kind" and "category" are two different models with own ID and same relationship with "recipe".

I have the association:

**recipe.rb**

```
belongs_to :kind
belongs_to :category
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :recipes, :only => "index" do
    collection do
        get :kind, :to => "recipes#index", :path => ":kind_id"
        get :category, :to => "recipes#index", :path => ":category_id"
    end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
kind_recipes GET    /receitas/:kind_id(.:format)     recipes#index
category_recipes GET    /receitas/:category_id(.:format) recipes#index
```

**recipes#index**

```
if params[:kind_id]
    @kind = Kind.find_by_slug(params[:kind_id])
    @recipes = @kind.recipes

elsif params[:category_id]
    @category = Category.find_by_slug(params[:category_id])
    @recipes = @category.recipes
end
```

When I access "recipes/drinks" (drinks is a "category_id") the passed parameter is "kind_id" because the route order.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Rails does routing it doesn't actually look in your DB for matching data.  So without looking at data, your two routes are exactly the same, the variable (kind_id & category_id) is just named different.  If you get a request on example /recipes/some_name, rails will just match the first one since both routes match the request.

You need something in the path that indicates its a category or kind.  If you will really never have a category and kind with the same name, then you could just have one route and try to match a category or kind from the DB in the controller.

Comment: Isee. What a pity!

Thanks @PierrePretorius for the answer.

I thought that I was passing parametres from routes to controller (:kind_id and :category_id). So if I put all together in category (categories and kinds) can I normally use counter_cache? Is important to know that "kinds" and "categories" are required. So I can't use only category_id for counter_cache, I will need something like a category_id and category_kind_id on recipes table for working with counter_cache.

Could you understand me?

Comment: I'm thinking that I have to change my associations to "many-to-many" (like a "tag way") to do the right thing about counter_cache, right?

Comment: You could also add a method to the recipes_model called 'tag_count' which internally adds the counter cache of kind's and categories.

Comment: Hi @PierrePretorius I already did that, but I've added a "recipe_count" to the tags_model. Could you help me in this new approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339571/edit-update-collection-select-with-has-many-through-association