# edit/update collection_select with has-many-through association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have the following models: RECIPE, TAG and TAGGING (join table)

recipe.rb

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :taggings
```

tag.rb

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :recipes, through: :taggings

scope :diet, -> { where(type_id: 1).to_a }
scope :category, -> { where(type_id: 2).to_a }
scope :festivity, -> { where(type_id: 3).to_a }
scope :daily, -> { where(type_id: 4).to_a }
```

Everything normal so far. But, in my TAGS table I have a field called "type_id" which brings me a kind of categorization of my tags. So I've created some "scopes" to distinguish each other.

tagging.rb

```
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => :recipes_count
```

recipes_controller.rb

```
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @recipe.tags.build
    @recipe.taggings.build(:recipe => @recipe)
end

def edit
end
```

my form

```
= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.build do |builder| 
    = builder.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.diet, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.build do |builder| 
    = builder.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.category, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.build do |builder| 
    = builder.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.festivity, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.build do |builder| 
    = builder.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.daily, :id, :name
```

When I create a NEW RECIPE the tags are added in join table (taggings) normally. But when I edit the collection_select helper does not mark as "selected" the item.

**How to construct the collection_select with many scopes?**

**How to construct the collection_select for EDIT/UPDATE actions?**

**Is there another better way to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.order("id").first do |diet|
    = diet.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.diet, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.order("id").second do |category| 
    = category.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.category, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.order("id").third do |festivity| 
    = festivity.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.festivity, :id, :name

= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.order("id").fourth do |daily| 
    = daily.collection_select :tag_id, Tag.daily, :id, :name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings do |builder|
```

Instead of

```
= f.fields_for :taggings, @recipe.taggings.build do |builder|
```

Because you are returning new tagging everytime instead of re-using the previously created ones.

Comment: Thanks @MarcAlexandreBerube, but it does not work for me. I think the problem is all about my scopes. With your answer (which I already tried) brings me just only one scope. I divided my tags in 4 differents scopes: Tag.diet, Tag.category, Tag.festivity, Tag.daily. I cannot put all types tag in the same place. Would you understand me? obs.: sorry my english!